# Can't load Google Map in fragment activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am working on a project which has google map configuration and view. 
But i can't see google map on the activity. The map has been loaded but not showing the details. Please see the image give.

[image]

See there is Google logo in left bottom corner. but still not showing the map on screen.

Following is Menifest.xml

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="key------" />
<permission
        android:name="com.roadyo.passenger.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.MAPS_RECIEVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

Comment: Have you added the map API key?

Comment: Check your logcat and see weather there is some problem in api key or not.This happens generally due to wrong api key

Comment: Do you get any warnings/errors in console?

Answer (score 1):

Please check your api key.

Follow this link to generate api key for google maps

[Google map console](https://code.google.com/apis/console)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how to use maps in our app, it gives step by step implementation of it, including registering app foe google APIs...

http://javapapers.com/android/android-show-current-location-on-map-using-google-maps-api/

Comment: Thank for the quick reply but i did that already. :) i followed all steps as in this tutorial :( but not working . the same thing is working on another project.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Sha1 and package name used to generate the api key. I have also got this error when i checked it its beacause of the mistake in package name and i regenerated the key by changing the package and i got it correctly